# Mounting TV to unusual existing mount

Tags: mounting, television

I have problem with using a TV wall mount left by previous owner. Remaining is a wall plate part with a single lug (3 1/8" long, 1/2" hole).

I never saw something partial like that. Usually the hinge part is integral and capped, then wall plate can be bolted into the wall.

Here the wall attachment is solid, but I can't find anything that has a pin and would secure a pin in the hinge assembly. Specifically, commercially-available part that attaches to TV itself and has a pin to insert into existing lug.

Could someone advise what options/designs are available?

[image]

Comment: Adapt it to what purpose?  Gravity would keep  a pin in if it has a good welded joint to whatever it is Adapted to. "*Could someone advise how to make it work?*"  How to make it work for what exactly?

Comment: I have had one just like that the pin had a E clip that held it in place other than gravity the clip really was not necessary mine had 2 joints in the arm and would be worthless without the mount you might ask the old owners for the rest of the mount.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, I meant to make it work for the same purpose of hanging a TV. Adapt -  in a sense to make this joint act like proper secure hinge. Yes, gravity will hold. But it needs a part where TV side plate/cross morphs into a slightly displaced downward pointing pin. I understand functional surfaces, but  could not find what such odd thing is called, nor where it retails.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, thx, edited the post to make it clearer.

Comment: @EdBeal, yes, could you advise what that "rest of the mount" may be called and where to find it? :)

Comment: I wish I could,  I left that house 10 years ago but it was similar I think I purchased it at video only Almost 20 years ago. slightly wider it was 16” wide  from the 6 screws this is different and may be a home made version to connect into the header. Slightly different than the one I purchased this is why I suggested to contact the people you bought the house from.